# RemObjects SDK, EOleError with message ‘Could not obtain OLE control window handle’ in Delphi

Tags: delphi, remobjects

I'm trying to create a Delphi RemObjects SDK Combo Service/Standalone project.

I could put an ActiveX control on the form.
But If run it, it crashes with an error message, "Project NewProjectClient.exe raised exception class EOleError with message 'Could not obtain OLE control window handle'.".

What is going wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: What does Google tell you about [Could not obtain OLE control window  handle](https://www.google.com/search?q=could+not+obtain+ole+control+window+handle&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8)?

Answer (score 0):

Any application that wants to use COM/ActiveX/OLE, must call [`CoInitialize`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms678543(v=vs.85).aspx) or [`CoInitializeEx`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms695279(v=vs.85).aspx) at least once, ideally during start-up. (Or [`OleInitialize`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms690134(v=vs.85).aspx) which itself calls `CoInitialize`)